Can't find substrate-node-template
I'm new to substrate.I'm following the a tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G897F8Gw1PM&list=PL5dTjWUk_cPYdb4j2RH8BHEAK3z_ZME1j&index=2 and the substrate docs to build a local blockchain.And I'm to clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template . But the repository doesn't exist anymore and I can't seem to find any update on it. Can someone help me out?

Pop CLI provides many parachain templates: https://learn.onpop.io/v/appchains

https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/polkadot_sdk_docs/polkadot_sdk/templates/index.html here you find the links to all the relevant templates.
